# Keeping data per open instance of a device

Tags: windows, device-driver, wdk

In a Windows device driver:

- **per-driver** information is stored in global variables
- **per-device** information is stored in the `DEVICE_OBJECT.DeviceExtension`

As far as I understand, a `CreateFile` constructs a `FILE_OBJECT` in the kernel space, so each open instance of a device has its own `FILE_OBJECT`. If so, can I keep my per-instance information in the `IO_STACK_LOCATION.FileObject.FsContext` field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the FsContext discription of the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff545834%28v=VS.85%29.aspx?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28%22WDM/IOGETCURRENTIRPSTACKLOCATION%22%29;k%28IOGETCURRENTIRPSTACKLOCATION%29;k%28SOLUTIONITEMSPROJECT%29;k%28DevLang-%22C%20%20%22%29;k%28TargetOS-WINDOWS%29&rd=true) says yes for FDOs and no for other types of drivers.

NB: Do you implement your own IRP_MJ_CREATE function? If yes, you may use the member, due to you being the creator of the file object.

Comment: Re implementing your own IRP_MJ_CREATE, great point. That seems to be precisely the distinction between when you should and shouldn't use FsContext.